# ImportError: cadquery was unable to determine freecad library path

Tags: python, python-2.7, freecad, cadquery

I am trying to run code from [this source](https://zenodo.org/record/1322839#.YZYexGDMJPZ://). The code is written in python 2, so I am using virtual environment with anaconda. The code replies on rather old versions of cadquery 1.2.0, which I installed into conda environment using pip. I also installed FreeCAD with the procedure described in the [this page](https://wiki.freecadweb.org/Conda). When I ran the coed I get the following error:

`ImportError: cadquery was unable to determine freecad library path`

The full output is:

```
  File "generate_hilbert_curve.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cadquery as cq
  File "/Users/vid/opt/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cadquery/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .freecad_impl.geom import Plane,BoundBox,Vector,Matrix,sortWiresByBuildOrder
  File "/Users/vid/opt/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cadquery/freecad_impl/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    path = _fc_path()
  File "/Users/vid/opt/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cadquery/freecad_impl/__init__.py", line 145, in _fc_path
    raise ImportError('cadquery was unable to determine freecad library path')
ImportError: cadquery was unable to determine freecad library path
```

What are potential sources of error and possible solutions?